# MaterialDatePicker returning wrong value

Tags: android, materialdatepicker

I am using `MaterialDatePicker` in android studio for the user to be able to choose the date of birth, after selecting the date, the returned value is a `long` with the timestamp of the selected date (milliseconds since 01/01/1970). The problem is that the result obtained is slightly wrong, example: If the user selects the date 10/05/1998 (1st of October 1998), the date returned is one day before this, that is, the calendar returns 10/04 / 1998 (October 4, 1998).

My code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = 
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();

picker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), picker.toString());

picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(selection);
    
         SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
             SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM//yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
                
          txtBirthDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }
});
```

The `calendar` instance, now with timeInMillis has the selected date, only a day before. How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you checking if date is wrong ? Are you using a date format for it ? if yes than add the format with question

Comment: @ADM i edited the question, and yes, ia m using SimpleDateFormat. But even if a get the returned long and use it in a timestamp converter site, it returns the wrong day, so the problem is on the returned value from the calendar.

Comment: Is there a solution?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I got the same situation today, I have to add 1 day to it manually.

Comment: @SamChen I'm facing the same issue. Do you know why is the date one day before?

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 Answer added.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Answer added.

Answer (score 5):

**【Working solution in 2022】**

It turns out that the `MaterialDatePicker` uses [UTC time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which means
it doesn't contain any **Time Zone** information, as the official states [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/00dc4c6b5af3939418f1c7d1e4c737dc3fb7fd67/docs/components/Picker.md#timezones).

That means we have to do some conversion work between **UTC date-time** and the **zone date-time**, the idea would be using the [LocalDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime) api:

**1. For showing correct date on picker, we need to convert zone date-time to UTC date-time:**

```
Zone date-time (Long) -> zone LocalDateTime (object) -> UTC date-time (object)-> UTC date-time (Long).
```

**2.  For getting zone date-time from picker, we need to convert UTC date-time to zone date-time:**

```
UTC date-time (Long) -> UTC LocalDateTime (object) -> zone date-time (object) -> zone date-time (Long)
```

---

1. Create Helper Extension Functions:

   ```
   fun Long.toLocalDateTime() = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(this), ZoneId.systemDefault())

   fun Long.toUTCLocalDateTime() = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(this), ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.UTC))
   ```
2. Show `MaterialDatePicker` in `Fragment`:

   ```
   private fun showDatePicker() {
       val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().run {
           setTitleText("Select Date")
           setSelection(viewModel.dateLong.value.toLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
           //setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()) //show today's date
           build()
       }

       datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
           val dateLong = datePicker.selection!!.toUTCLocalDateTime().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli() 

           viewModel.updateDateLong(dateLong)       
       }

        datePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "")
    }
   ```

Demo: https://youtu.be/9YWr3fgQ214

Comment: This GitHub issue also confirms this behavior. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/882#issuecomment-1111378306

Answer (score 0):

This is because DatePicker indexes the months from 0 override this method

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    datePickerListener.onDateSet(view,year,month+1,dayOfMonth)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was converting the desired timestamp to `LocalDateTime` first, then truncating to `DAYS` and finally converting it to `UTC` like following:

```
val selection = ZonedDateTime.now()
    .toLocalDateTime()
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .toEpochMilli()

val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    .setSelection(selection)
    //...
    .build()
```

Then you can get the picked date as follows:

```
picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection ->
    val selectedDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(selection)
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())

    //...
}
```